# Serilog - Unable to open file - File used by another process Error

Tags: file, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I'm using serilog in a .NetCore 3.1 application.

```
loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.File("test-{Date}.txt").CreateLogger();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

When i run a application and try to access file, i'm getting error saying
"File cannot be opened because it is being used by another process"

Am i missing any setting to be added?

Update:

Even after adding shared:true - Did not work.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.Async( o => o.File("test1.txt", shared: true)).CreateLogger();
```

Comment: The Serilog File Sink [opens the file with shared reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) so something else is locking the file, not Serilog. You might want to try to use the [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) utility to see which process is locking the log file